# PHP Show message if account_first_name are blank or empty ( echo if empty ?)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, echo

!

I would like to see on my page a simple text which reminds the subscriber has to edit are preson name and in his profile.

This text would show only if the wordpress user profile name is empty.

Someone has an idea of php code?

I have this on my HTML profil page, as input.

When this input is empty I would like to display a little message in php.

input class="**input-text**" name="**account_first_name**" id="**account_first_name**" value="" type="text"

Tank you, am using woocommerce

Comment: sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Maybe placeholder is what you want?

```
<input class="input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="" type="text" placeholder="Remember to edit this!">
```

If not and you want to use PHP to check if a variable is empty then use the empty function.

```
<?php
$name = "";
if(empty($name)){
  echo "Remember to edit name";
}
?>
```